# Issue displaying value in number field AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I am trying to bind a value which of type `string` when it comes from the `controller` in a `numeric input` field like the following:

`<input type="number" ng-model="detail.Value">`

Since the `detail.Value` is of type `string`, I value is not getting displayed (I guess).

**I can not change the Value property's type to int.**

**What can I do in the view to display the value in the number box?**

Comment: are these data comes from db ?

Comment: Yes kind of, I am saving them into a $scope variable and displaying them @KalhanoToressPamuditha I am getting the values as JSON object and assigning them.. to be precise I am returning a List of object

Comment: i also had this problem. what i did is change the db column data type to integer or double or some numeric type.

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha in my case I can't do that that's the sad part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with `parseFloat`:

```
 detail.Value = parseFloat(detail.Value);
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2298/)</kbd>

Comment: @RandomUser do you mean in HTML?

Comment: @RandomUser the answer is NO, you can't use `ng-model` with function. But i suggest you to make it anyways in controller. Not big dial.

Comment: @mMaximShoustin in the fiddle I am not able to see `123` in the number box

Comment: well, it should work in Chrome, firefox, IE and Safari

Answer (score 1):

You can either to pass that value to the method on a controller which will do the parsing (and assigning to the model) or if you really want to do that in HTML you can assign parsing method to the scope in the controller (`$scope.parseFloat = parseFloat;`) and than parse in `ng-init`. Something like this: `ng-init="value = parseFloat(detail.Value)"` and then `ng-model="value"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.isNumeric = function isNumber(number) {               // function to test the data can be convert to numeric
     return !isNaN(parseFloat(number)) && isFinite(number);
}
```

```
...success(data) {      // after getting the data from serverside
    var formData = data.formDataWithNumeric; // get the form data
    for (key in formData) {                  //iterate through the data
        var isNumericData = $scope.isNumeric(formData[key]);  // check data can be convert to a numeric
        if(isNumericData) {
            formData[key] = Number(formData[key]);  // reassign the numeric value instead of string value
        }
    }
}
```

you can try something like this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small directive to force the model value to be a number

```js
   function forceNumber ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
           var getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
           var setter = getter.assign;
           var remListner = attrs.$observe('ngModel', function (val) {
              var value = getter(scope);
              if (typeof value !== 'number') {
                 setter(scope,+value);
              }
              // remove listner, no need to keep watching!
              remListner();
           });
        }
    };
   }
```

you can see it in action in [this small plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7s5n6OW3zu9fm3qTWfo?p=preview)

Hope this helps you,
Regards
Sander

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save the plunk :) done now, and updated my answer!